# PHP openID integration in Magento

Tags: php, magento, openid

Can anybody tell me how multiple-openid authentication works here in Stack Overflow? I have this doubt since I want to implement the same functionality in my new magento site. The only doubt I have is, if I login using openID I will be using my unique url (eg:http://example.myopenid.com).  Now, when I want to shop something, I must receive an email of confirmation, how do I receive that without entering it anywhere?

A similar scenario is in the current site, ie. stackoverflow.com. I am posting this question using my openid authentication. Now, how would I know if someone posts answers to my question, or if some one comments on it? Please help me know this.

Answer (score 1):

It uses back end authentication, which eventually passes on the Email address, and then Magento uses the Login User By Email function to get the user logged in.

The system knows your email address throughout the session, and any system emails can then be sent to you.

Look at this plugin for some ideas:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-through-social-networks-and-more-multilogin-11-in-1.html

let me know if you need more explaining.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and also sorry for replying so late. I got the solution for this issue. I hacked the magento code and got the functionality done using opendId class.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the [Flagbit "magento-openid" project](https://github.com/Flagbit/magento-openid) to enable manager login via OpenID.
But I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is another free project https://github.com/dachcom-digital/magento-openid which works with current Magento versions